# Combinatorics: Number of ways to split a sample equally and randomly.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a sample of *n* scans, which I divide equally and randomly into two sub-samples of size *m=n/2*. How many **unique** sub-samples am I able to make in this manner from the original sample size of *n* scans, please?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit**

So, if I have 4 scans *a,b,c* and *d*, then the **unique**, equal combinations of this are:

1. *a,b* and *c,d*
2. *a,c* and *b,d*
3. *a,d* and *b,c*

which is just *4 choose 2* divided by 2 = 3? And therefore on a generic scale *n choose n / 2* divided by 2?

Comment: Do you know about combinations and permutations?

Comment: n choose n/2?  If I understand you correctly, you're asking how many different ways can I select k = n/2 objects from n objects.  That's just n choose k.

Comment: @Adam I think that may be what I'm after. I'm trying to make as many unique two sub-samples of size *n/2* as possible.

Comment: @Adam I've just edited the question with an example to clarify what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you'll have exactly 
$$
\frac{1}{2}{n \choose \frac{n}{2}}
$$

possible choices. Note that, having selected a specific sample (that is, $\frac{n}{2}$ elements of the possible $n$), this determines the other sub-sample, since we have exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ scans left. There are ${n \choose \frac{n}{2}}$ possible choices of a first sample. However, one must take into account that choosing some sample or it's complement gives the same outcome. A concrete example as in your original question: if I pick $\{c,d\}$ first, this determines the other sub sample as $\{a,b\}$, and the same is achieved when selecting $\{a,b\}$ first. This is why we only count half of the previously proposed cases.